# face_recognition and black&white images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, face-recognition, dlib

I'm using [face_recognition library](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) to recognise persons on images.
According to the [library documentation](https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/face_recognition.html), it supports two input image formats for further processing: RGB (8 bit, 3 channels) and L (black and white).

I tried to use

```
face_recognition.api.load_image_file(file, mode='RGB')
```

and it's ok. But I need to use L-mode and that's the point. Problem is that mode='RGB' generates numpy.array (x,y,3) and mode='L' generates numpy.array(x,y).

Array should be input later to face_recognition.face_locations and face_recognition.face_encodings functions.

If we put array, which was generated in L-mode to face_encodings, we get the following error:

```
    TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
        1. (self: dlib.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),uint8], face: dlib.full_object_detection, num_jitters: int=0) -> dlib.vector
        2. (self: dlib.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),uint8], faces: dlib.full_object_detections, num_jitters: int=0) -> dlib.vectors
        3. (self: dlib.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),uint8]], batch_faces: List[dlib.full_object_detections], num_jitters: int=0) -> dlib.vectorss
```

Any ideas, how should I use this library for black&white images to obtain 128-dimensional facemaps?

Full listing that throws an error (you can use any person's image as image.jpg):

```
    import face_recognition
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file('image.jpg', mode='L')
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, face_locations)
```

Traceback:

File "D:/PythonProjects/face_recognition_grayscale_test.py", line 18, in 
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, face_locations)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 200, in face_encodings
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 200, in 
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]

TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: dlib.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),uint8], face: dlib.full_object_detection, num_jitters: int=0) -> dlib.vector
    2. (self: dlib.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),uint8], faces: dlib.full_object_detections, num_jitters: int=0) -> dlib.vectors
    3. (self: dlib.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),uint8]], batch_faces: List[dlib.full_object_detections], num_jitters: int=0) -> dlib.vectorss

Invoked with: , array([[167, 167, 167, ..., 172, 172, 170],
       [167, 167, 167, ..., 172, 172, 170],
       [167, 167, 167, ..., 172, 172, 170],
       ...,
       [188, 186, 181, ..., 201, 201, 198],
       [193, 189, 184, ..., 201, 201, 198],
       [181, 180, 178, ..., 201, 201, 198]], dtype=uint8), , 1

Comment: Include a [mcve] of the code that produced the error, and a full traceback.

Comment: @HåkenLid I just done that. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [face\_recognition problem with face\_encodings function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75926662/face-recognition-problem-with-face-encodings-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message it looks like it doesn't accept single channel images. You need an ndarray of (rows, cols, 3). You could try to pass in `image.repeat(3, 2)` which will just repeat the L values three times.

```
face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image.repeat(3, 2), face_locations)
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea. But it needs some addition: at first `image = image[:,:,newaxis]` and after that `image = image.repeat(3,2)` so this worked. Just using repeat throws an error `AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 2` Thx again.

Comment: Quoting from https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/436#issuecomment-379344211:

The three separate channels of information in a color photo gives you 3x more data to pass into the model than one channel of data from a B/W photo. So if you pass a B/W image instead of color, you are throwing away valuable data (two thirds of your data) that could be used to increase accuracy.