# Getting error while calling the face_recognition.face_encodings(img, face_locations) in Ubuntu & RasbianOS

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition, dlib, pybind11

I tried running an face recognition with face_recognition library available in Python. while running when it detects the face it is throwing an exception mentioning there is parameter mismatch, but in same condition, same code works well in Windows, but with any of the Linux based operating system I am facing this problem.

```py
face_recognition.face_encodings(img, face_locations)
```

The code line mentioned above raising the exception `TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments.`

As I can see the documentation, passed function parameters are correct and works pretty well in Windows. I observed whenever the face is getting detected and passing the face_locations as a parameters it is raising the error, Type of face_locations is list of tuple with detected face cordinates.

Tested implementation with Python3.7 & Python3.8 with dlib==19.24.1, face_recognition==1.3.0, face_recognition_models==0.3.0.

Tested above implementation with Python3.7 & Python3.8 with dlib==19.24.1, face_recognition==1.3.0, face_recognition_models==0.3.0. Same configuration works well in windows but not in linux.

Comment: Found similar issue on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737213/face-recognition-and-blackwhite-images

Comment: Yes, tested the same but doesn't work well for me.